# Get specific element inside hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem to get specific img inside div(display none):

```
<a onclick="showhide_class()" title="show" class="showhide"><img src="image_small_1.jpg" /></a>
<div class="content"><img src="image_big_1.jpg" />
    <a onclick="showhide_class()"><img class="close" src="x.png" alt="x"></a>
</div>
<a onclick="showhide_class()" title="show" class="showhide"><img src="image_small_2.jpg" /></a>
<div class="content"><img src="image_big_2.jpg" />
    <a onclick="showhide_class()"><img class="close" src="x.png" alt="x"></a>
</div>
<a onclick="showhide_class()" title="show" class="showhide"><img src="image_small_..n.jpg" /></a>
<div class="content"><img src="image_big_..n.jpg" />
    <a onclick="showhide_class()"><img class="close" src="x.png" alt="x"></a>
</div>
```

so there is the js code:

```
function showhide_class(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].style.display == 'none') {
        elements[i].style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
```

When I click on "`image_small_2.jpg`" I need to get "`image_big_2.jpg`"

but when I click on "`image_small_1.jpg`" or second image - it shows the last one "`image_big_..n.jpg`".

I also tried to get img in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".showhide").on("click", function(){
    $(".content").css("display","block");
  });
});
```

it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your inner `a` also a distinct class, like `hide`, and remove the `onclick` attributes on all of them:

```
<a title="show" class="showhide">show<img src="image_small_1.jpg" /></a>
<div class="content"><img src="image_big_1.jpg" />
    <a class="hide"><img class="close" src="x.png" alt="x">close</a>
</div>
<a title="show" class="showhide">show<img src="image_small_2.jpg" /></a>
<div class="content"><img src="image_big_2.jpg" />
    <a class="hide"><img class="close" src="x.png" alt="x">close</a>
</div>
<a title="show" class="showhide"><img src="image_small_..n.jpg" /></a>
<div class="content"><img src="image_big_..n.jpg" />
    <a class="hide"><img class="close" src="x.png" alt="x"></a>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery, attach the event handlers for the two types of `a` you have:

```
$('a.showhide').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.content:first').toggle();
});

$('a.hide').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.content').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's great!